# determine whether group is additive

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetry

I am taking a stab at group theory and in some of the questions I am working on they don't explicitly state whether a group is additive or multiplicative. $\mathbb{Z}_4$ is additive (and that makes sense because integers) but how do I for example determine the operation to use on $\mathbb{R}$? It seems like it could be either one (it satisfies the axioms for both) and it's not clear as to what the question wants. Is there a rule as to what I should do when?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If $R$ is a multiplicative group so what's the symmetric element of $0$?

Comment: What is the difference between an additive group and a multiplicative group supposed to be?

Comment: @almagest I think the question is, given the underlying set of a group, guess the group operation.  Fortunately, it seems to be presupposed that the operation has to be addition or multiplication.  And fortunately in the particular examples in the question, only one of these two operations produces a group (contrary to the parenthetical claim in hte question).

Comment: Sorry if I'm unclear. I'm not very experienced. I mean that the group is closed under addition/multiplication. The question I am working with is asking that I find the order of 3 in the group R8. I'm not sure whether this means addition or multiplication.

Comment: @almagest presumably the book is asking him the question, "is $\mathbb{R}$ a group under its usual addition, or multiplication?" and similarly for various sets

Comment: @arlyon could you tell us how they've defined the group R8? I'm not familiar with that notation

Comment: This is how it is written: Find ord(r<sup>2</sup>s) in D<sub>13</sub> and ord(3) in R<sub>8</sub>

Looks like the super/sub tags dont work in comments..

Comment: The question doesnt use $\mathbb{R}$ however. It uses the notation in the first comment. I've sent an email for clarification. It seems just as obscure to me as it is to everyone else. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

A group $G$ is a group, and as such is endowed with a single binary operation $$\star: \quad G\times G\to G, \qquad(x,y)\mapsto x\star y$$
satisfying certain axioms. If no optional properties of $\star$ are assumed the operation $\star$ is called *multiplication* in $G$. If in the case at hand  the operation $\star$ is commutative, as is the addition of integers, we are inclined to call the operation $\star$  *addition*, and write $+$ instead of $\star$. This notational move becomes a necessity if on $G$ additional binary operations, like $*$,  are installed which interact in a particular way with $+$.